# Qt creator Debugging existing CMake project - "error loading shared libraries"

Tags: linux, cmake, makefile, qt-creator

I have an existing project with C++ files. I opened that project on Qt and went to Debug->Start debugging, but I get an error message 
`/opt/apps/ossw/applications/gcc/gcc-4.6/sl6/libexec/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.6.3/cc1plus:-1: error: error while loading shared libraries: libmpc.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

I don't understand why I'm getting this because I never got this error when I compiled before using `CMakeLists` and `make` on Linux

When I tried to search for that file, I see a ton of directories, but they all also say `Permission denied` on the command prompt

What can I do to resolve this?

Comment: Could You please share Your `CMakeLists.txt`, at least parts relevant to`libmpc`? The `QtCreator` might be missing some searcher script or You've just installed `libmpc` to some non-standard location. Also, what Operating System are You running?

Comment: I am using Scientific Linux, my CMakeLists.txt can be seen here: http://pastebin.com/QFDyTDz5

Comment: cheesus, what the heck? Does not seam like a normal CMakeLists.txt. Also can't see any relation to `mpc`.